# Is possible to automate OAuth 2.0 implicit grant flow of Azure active directory in postman?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, postman

I'm trying to automate all the testing of an API. Currently is using a utentificacion using AAD. 
The problem is: I can use the process of postman to get the token using OAuth2.0

**Postman dialog**

[image]

but I can't run a collection and do something like a trigger to get the token at the beginning. If i want to take the token I must push the button "Get new access token"

there is some way to do it automatically? or how can I create a flow to obtain the token?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use Pre-request Script to do it automatically. You just need to modify your required value and post it in the Pre-request Script of the postman. It had better in the parent collection, so it could inherit auth from the parent.

```html
var getToken = true;

if (!pm.environment.get('accessTokenExpiry') || 
    !pm.environment.get('currentAccessToken')) {
    console.log('Token or expiry date are missing')
} else if (pm.environment.get('accessTokenExpiry') <= (new Date()).getTime()) {
    console.log('Token is expired')
} else {
    getToken = false;
    console.log('Token and expiry date are all good');
}

if (getToken === true) {
    pm.sendRequest({
         url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token',
    method: 'POST',
    header: 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: 'grant_type=implicit&client_id...'
    }
    }, function (err, res) {
    console.log(err ? err : res.json());
        if (err === null) {
            console.log('Saving the token and expiry date')
            var responseJson = res.json();
            pm.environment.set('currentAccessToken', responseJson.access_token)
    
            var expiryDate = new Date();
            expiryDate.setSeconds(expiryDate.getSeconds() + responseJson.expires_in);
            pm.environment.set('accessTokenExpiry', expiryDate.getTime());
        }
    });
}
```

For the code sample, you could refer to [here](https://gist.github.com/bcnzer/073f0fc0b959928b0ca2b173230c0669).

Comment: Where do I need to add my actual auth credential? (I mean Microsoft credentials)

Comment: This does not answer the question: this answer is based on https://gist.github.com/bcnzer/073f0fc0b959928b0ca2b173230c0669 but this is for Client Credentials flow, not Implicit flow.